# UIPicker View doesn't respond touch fully on action sheet

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I added a `UIPicker` view on action sheet and called on text Field touch.
action sheet appears picker shows but picker doesn't respond touch properly only selection bar of picker responds touch.

Comment: Could you post some of the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

One reason of this happening is if you are displaying it on top of a tabbar and using the option

```
[selectYearOfBirth showInView:(UIView *)]

rather use the option 

[selectYearOfBirth showFromTabBar:(UITabBar *)]
```

This should solve your problem if i am right